# Postgresql: Using german umlaut doesn't work from C++ program (PQexec) but works from console/pgadmin

Tags: c++, postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, psql

So I am using postgresql in C++ application. I can, without any problems, use german umlaute (Ä,Ö,Ü) in update statements from within PGAdmin or the Windows CMD.

But when I create the same update query in C++ in a char* or std::string and try to execute it with PQexec, it doesn't work and PQexec returns an error value.

Postgresql returns German_Germany.1252 for `show lc_collate;` and `show lc_ctype;` and returns `UTF8` for `server encoding;`.

Does someone know what the problem may be?

Edit: Also when I debug the C++ code, Visual Studio shows the query just fine. But when I output it using cout or printf, the umlaut characters are not displayed correctly. I don't know if that's of any relevance.

Comment: What is the error you get from `PQexec`? to what value did you set `client_encoding` or the environment variable `PGCLIENTENCODING`?

Comment: show client_encoding returns win1525. Sadly it seems like VS doesn't show the content of the PGexec result, but it's not PGRES_COMMAND_OK as it is if there is no umlaut character in the query.

Comment: Use `PQresultErrorMessage` on the result of `PQexec` to get the error message. Also, it might be good to show the C++ code you are using. Is the command you are executing encoded in WIN-1252?

Comment: Oh, thanks. The error is "invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”" (well, it's in german and the umlaute are also not displayed properly)

Comment: Then I would suspect that your `client_encoding` is *not* `win1252` in your C++ application - otherwise PostgreSQL would not complain about incorrect UTF-8 characters. Maybe you can run `SHOW client_encoding` in your C++ program and display the result to check.